# return type for displaying the duplicates

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am a method to find duplicates in a `DataTable`. Now I have to return the duplicates values if exists in the main code block and display in `comma separated` form.

How should I edit my method to return the duplicate values and display in `comma separated` form?

```
// what should be the return type of this method ???
public Find_Duplicate_Symbol_Number(DataTable dt)
{
    try
    {
        var dup_result = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     group c by new
                     {
                         RowId = c.Field<string>("SYMBOL_NO")
                     } into g
                     where g.Count() > 1
                     select new
                     {
                         g.Key.RowId
                     };

        // how to return dup_result ???             
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
} 

/// ** main code block ** ///
Find_Duplicate_Symbol_Number(DataTable dt)
```

How to call this function from main code block and show the duplicate values in comma separated form if duplicates exist?

Comment: What is a comma separated form? Do you just want a string with all values together? Have a look at `string.join`

Comment: As you stated the expected return values will be a comma separated, then the type will be string right?

Comment: @sujithkarivelil Yes, but the duplicates may be multiple. So if return type will be string, how to display multiple duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS. Please suggest.

Comment: @GiladGreen Suppose there are 2 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS. So the message printed should be `2 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found 00157 & 00158`. So how to do this?

Comment: Can you make it a `Dictionary<string,int>` where `string` is the symbol(s) and `int` for count?

Comment: "Suppose there are 2 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS. So the message printed should be 2 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found 00157 & 00158. So how to do this? " ...you've put the clause `where g.Count() > 1`, so surely they are _all_ duplicates?

Comment: @Sami How can I return this var as List variable and display in comma separated form?

Comment: @nischalinn - see answer below

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) to concatenate all the numbers together:

```
public string FindDuplicateSymbolNumber(DataTable dt) 
{
    return string.Join(", ", from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             group 1 by c.Field<string>("SYMBOL_NO") into g
                             where g.Skip(1).Any()
                             select g.Key.RowId);
}
```

Also see the changes in the query - no need to project anonymous types containing a single field, just project the field. In addition instead of counting (and consuming the entire collection), just skip the first item in each group and check if after it there are still any more items - meaning more than a single item in the group.

---

If all you want is to return the list of duplicate ids then:

```
public IEnumerable<string> FindDuplicateSymbolNumber(DataTable dt) 
{
    return from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
           group 1 by c.Field<string>("SYMBOL_NO") into g
           where g.Skip(1).Any()
           select g.Key.RowId;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to return the found duplicates as `List` and display as comma separated form. Please suggest. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you have a DataTable with a column SYMBOL_NO. This column contains a string value. You want to count all duplicate string values in this column and display it in format:

2 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found 00157 & 00158

Where instead of 2 you want the actual number of found duplicates, and instead of 00157 and 00158 you want the actual duplicate symbols

It will be easier for you to understand your problem and to test the solution if you don't put all code in one function. Separate your code into smaller functions:

- (A) Given an input DataTable, return from every row the string value at column SYMBOL_NO.
- (B) Given an input enumerable sequence of strings, return every string from the input string that occurs more than once
- (C) given a sequence of strings, write a text similar to:

.

```
2 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found 00157 & 00158
```

Where instead of 2, the actual number of elements in the strings, and 00157 & 00158 the elements from the string. Keep in mind that there may be no duplicates. In that case:

```
0 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found
```

How about this:

```
DataTable dt = ...

// (A) extract the SYMBOL_NO
var string = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("SYMBOL_NO");

// (B) Find duplicates
// group the input texts into groups of same string 
// and remember if there are duplicates
```

.GroupBy(text => text,
       // ResultSelector: take the text (in Key) and all items with this Key
       (key, textsEqualToThisKey) => new
       {
           SymbolNo = text,
           IsDuplicate = textsEqualToThisKey.Skip(1).Any(), // more efficient than Count()
       })

```
// (C) Keep only those SymbolNos that have duplicates
.Where(group => group.IsDuplicate)
.Select(group => group.SymbolNo

// (D) From the remaining duplicates make a string
// TODO
```

The last one is the most difficult, because the text before the first item is different than the text before every other items. Furthermore, the text is different if there are no items found at all.

My advice would be to create an extension function, this would be the easiest way to understand what happens

```
static string ToDuplicateDescription(this IEnumerable<string> duplicates)
{

    var enumerator = duplicates.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // there is at least one duplicate. The first one is without ampersand
        int count = 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // add the count later
        sb.AppendFormat(" duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found {0}", enumerator.Current);

        // are there more duplicates?
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            ++count;
            sb.AppendFormat(" & {0}", enumerator.Current);
        }
        // if here, no more duplicates.
        return count.ToString() + sb.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // no duplicates at all
        return "0 duplicate SYMBOL NUMBERS found";
    }
}
```

Usage: (continuing the LINQ above)

```
 // (D) From the remaining duplicates make a string
 .ToDuplicateDescription();
```